# Yesterday's Date with Today's Information

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the second highest histNumber from the historyInformation table. As of right now, I get the second highest date with the first highest histNumber. How can I modify this query to get the second highest histNumber.

```
select id, max(histDate) yd, histNumber
from historyinformation
where histDate < (select max(histDate) from historyinformation)
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT histDate, histNumber FROM historyinformation
WHERE histNumber < (select max(histNumber))
ORDER BY histNumber DESC
LIMIT 1
```

You're just comparing the wrong thing in your WHERE clause. Filter your selection where histNumbers are less than the max. If you ORDER this by DESC, and limit 1, you get the second highest histNumber

Comment: The result has to contain both the histDate and histNumber from yesterday.

Comment: You just need to add in those fields instead of the *. I've updated answer